# Not able to access data outside the function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to call a variable outside the function where I called redux store.

```
import store from '../../store/store';

function getToken() {
  let newToken = store.getState();
  let token = newToken.auth.authToken;
  console.log(token);
}
store.subscribe(getToken);
```

This works fine.

But when I try this, this does not work

```
function getToken() {
  let newToken = store.getState()
  let token=newToken.auth.authToken;
  return token
}
store.subscribe(getToken);
console.log(getToken())
```

could someone please help me

Comment: What does the state return? Can you elaborate on what the store.getState() returned? If anything is returned, it need to be an object containing auth object which again contains authToken. Are this things returned?

Comment: did you try to log token before returning in second case?

Comment: Yes i did console.log

Answer (score 0):

```
let token;
function getToken() {
  let newToken = store.getState()
  token = newToken.auth.authToken;
  return token;
}
const reduxState = store.subscribe(getToken);
console.log(reduxState())
```

Can you try this and let me know if this works for you or not.